# Why did my PHP stop working?

Tags: php

I have some complex code. Complex, but it *was* working.

The I wanted to add some new code, realized that something needed to become a function and then went on a refactoring rampage. Now my code no longer works.

So I did a bit of file compare, some code reading and debugging, and convinced myself that my changes hadn't broken anything.

To test this theory, I put together an exceedingly simple test program:

```
<?php 
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mysql;Option=3;", "root", "");
var_dump($connection);
echo '<br>';
  $result = @odbc_exec($connection, 'show version()');
  var_dump($result);
?>
```

which resulted in

```
resource(2) of type (odbc link) 
bool(false)
```

The strange thing is that the odbc_connect() succeeds, but the simplest MySql command I can think of fails.

Btw, I have tested at the command line & the MySql server is up & running (Xampp) and reports v 5.1.41.

Obviously I am overlooking something very basic, but what?

Comment: @mawg take out the @ sign so you can see what error it's giving

Comment: Turn errors ON and remove the @ before odbc_exec. You might see something...

Comment: Why are you using ODBC to connect to MySQL?  Why not use either the native driver or PDO?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using ODBC here instead of PDO?

Comment: Did you find out what the error was? I have the same problem! (except that in my case ODBC connects to a sybase ASE database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the odbc driver "wants" to tell you something about what is causing the error...

```
$result = @odbc_exec($connection, 'show version()');
if ( !$result ) {
  printf("error: %d %s", odbc_error($connection), odbc_errormsg($connection));
}
else {
  echo "ok";
}
```

see http://docs.php.net/odbc_error and http://docs.php.net/odbc_errormsg

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest MYSQL query I can think of:

```
select 1
```

This should help you determine if your connection is working or if the problem lies elsewhere.